# Parsing phone numbers from website

Tags: php, html, parsing, curl

Trying to parse some phone numbers [from a website](http://www.baroul-bucuresti.ro/index.php?w=definitivi&l=C&p=1).

While I'm getting the source code via cURL, I get back only half of the code but the part that's missing is exactly what I need. This thing keeps bugging me.

My code so far:

```
$ch = curl_init("http://www.baroul-bucuresti.ro/index.php?w=definitivi&l=C&p=2");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
$content = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
print_r ($content);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem is that the url in question has a 302 in it, redirecting it to another location:

```
$ telnet www.baroul-bucuresti.ro 80
Trying 91.208.179.20...
Connected to www.baroul-bucuresti.ro.
Escape character is '^]'.
GET /index.php?w=definitivi&l=C&p=2 HTTP/1.1
host: www.baroul-bucuresti.ro

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Fri, 27 Apr 2012 20:24:54 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (CentOS)
X-Powered-By: PHP/5.3.3
Set-Cookie: PHPSESSID=qjbqvveqtmarv7o0f820bbeq71; path=/
Expires: Thu, 19 Nov 1981 08:52:00 GMT
Cache-Control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0
Pragma: no-cache
Set-Cookie: for_tablou=1
Set-Cookie: bvbsessionhash=b9c609e162dab90fc86c1fdb52e07fdd; expires=Sun, 27-May-2012 20:24:57 GMT; path=/
Set-Cookie: bvblastvisit=1335558297; expires=Sun, 27-May-2012 20:24:57 GMT; path=/
Set-Cookie: bvblastactivity=1335558297; expires=Sun, 27-May-2012 20:24:57 GMT; path=/
Set-Cookie: bvbuserid=deleted; expires=Thu, 28-Apr-2011 20:24:56 GMT; path=/
Set-Cookie: for_tablou=1
Location: /tablou
```

I've changed your code by adding this option to curl:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
```

And it seems to get the full contents now.. dont know if its the content you want, but it gets the full contents of the real location, could you give it a try?